# American options -- doing better than Black's approximation when $r = 0$

Tags: options, implied-volatility, american-options

I am trying to find the implied volatility smile for an American call option with a known dividend during the option tenor. For the sake of argument, let's say today is Jan 1, the dividend $D$ is paid out in 30 days at time $T_1$, and the option expires in 60 days at time $T_2$. Since $r = 0$, 
$$D < K(1-e^{-r(T-T_1)}) = 0$$
isn't satisfied, so it *may* be optimal to exercise at  $T_1$. In effect, we have a Bermudan option with possible exercise times $T_1$ and $T_2$. If I have price data for the option, how can I back out the implied volatility? Is there an additional simplification or approximation we can make since $r = 0$ that does better than [Black's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black's_approximation)?

Comment: Bumping this $\qquad$

Comment: Please don't bump